# Heroku Deployment - Model Error

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I am trying to deploy the Computer database java sample application on 
Heroku. Deployment is complete but getting the following error when 
accessing the pages:

```
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:63) 
[play_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at akka.actor.Actor 
$class.apply(Actor.scala:290) [akka-actor-2.0.jar:2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m play.core.ActionInvoker$ 
$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception 
[[PersistenceException: models.Computer is NOT an Entity Bean 
registered with this server?]] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:61) [play_2.9.1-2.0.jar: 
2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:617) [akka-actor-2.0.jar: 
2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Caused by: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: models.Computer is NOT an 
Entity Bean registered with this server? 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:179) [akka- 
actor-2.0.jar:2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java: 
1031) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java: 
988) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java: 
1024) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at play.db.ebean.Model 
$Finder.query(Model.java:258) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at play.db.ebean.Model 
$Finder.where(Model.java:706) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0] 
[32m2012-04-07T09:00:37+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at 
models.Computer.page(Computer.java:48) ~[computer- 
database_2.9.1-1.0.jar:1.0]
```

Can you please help... Source is the same as the github [computer-database](https://github.com/playframework/%20%20Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database) sample

-S

Answer (score 0):

I made the usual changes to run this on Heroku and it worked fine:
https://github.com/jamesward/Play20/commit/636216527b77477bfa1e523df813fa3cf33b15c0

Comment: Issue is resolved, it was because of some changes from my side.